# What environment variables can I use in custom behavior scripts in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, scripting, xcode4, behavior

Xcode 4 lets you create custom behaviors that are performed from the *Xcode > Behaviors* menu, or are triggered by a keyboard shortcut. One of the actions that can be taken is the execution of an application or shell script.

[image]

What variables or arguments are passed to the script that it can make use of?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The environment may be context specific (depending on what is selected in Xcode), but this will show the environment variables available in a given context:

Make a script file containing

```
#!/bin/sh
env | sort > ~/Xcode_behaviors.out
```

Don't forget to make the script executable.

Then create a new Xcode Behavior that calls the script file.  The output file contains the environment variables that are available.  See them with:

```
cat ~/Xcode_behaviors.out
```

Answer (score 7):

From my own experimentation, I found that Xcode sets the following environment variables before running a custom script:

- `XcodeDeveloperDirectory` -- the root path to your developer tools installation, i.e. */Developer*
- `XcodeDeveloperApplicationsDirectory` -- path to developer applications, i.e. */Developer/Applications*
- `XcodeDeveloperPlatformsLibrary` -- path to the developer platforms, i.e. */Developer/Platforms*
- `XcodeProject` -- name of the currently open project, i.e. *MyProject.xcodeproj*. This variable is not set if you have a workspace open.
- `XcodeWorkspace` -- name of the currently open workspace, i.e. *MyWorkspace.xcworkspace*.
- `XcodeWorkspacePath` -- path to the currently open workspace, i.e. */Users/You/Code/My iPhone App.xcworkspace*. If you have a single project open, this will be something like */Path/To/OpenProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace* instead.

Comment: `PWD` is another good one - the path where workspace/project is located

Comment: I also see `IDEAlertMessage=Build Succeeded`